# maven classpath order between dependency jars and src/main/resources?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to run 
mvn exec:java .....

then it uses the runtime classpath defined by my pom, which I think defaults to the compile classpath. the problem is that I found that my src/main/resources/log4j.xml  is not reflected, since I put DEBUG logging in the file, but I only see WARN in the output.
I suspect that it's actually the log4j.xml from some of the dependency jars that is being used.
so I need to elevate the src/main/resources/log4j.xml to the front of my compile/runtime classpath. but how do I specify the relative order of src/main/resources vs dependency jars in the classpath?

Thanks
Yang

Comment: +1 Good question.  `src/main/resources` is specified in the `<build>` section, which comes _after_ the `<dependencies>` section in the POM.

Comment: Try to run Maven with `-X` debug option and check the classpath for exec plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to explicitly specify the `log4j.xml` that you want log4j to use using a command-line argument.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j.xml
```

Comment: Thanks , I did try that, but somehow it does not work. it only works if I specify a log4j.properties instead